# Proof of Vitali Theorem in Jech's The Axiom of Choice uses a questionable statement about Measure

Tags: lebesgue-measure

Thomas J. Jech, on the second page of his *The Axiom of Choice* (1973) proves the existence of a nonmeasurable set of real numbers thus:

Let $\mu(X)$ denote the Lebesgue measure of a set $X$ of real numbers. We know that $\mu$ is countably additive and translation invariant, and that $\mu([a, b]) = b - a$ for every closed real interval $[a, b]$.

For $x, y \in [0, 1]$, define the relation $x \sim y$ if and only if $x - y$ is rational.

$\sim$ is a equivalence relation, so denote $[[x]]$ as the equivalence class with respect to $\sim$ for each $x \in [0, 1]$.

By the Axiom of Choice we can choose one element out of each equivalence class.

Thus we have a set $M$ of real numbers $M \subseteq [0, 1]$ which has the property that for each real $x$ there exists a unique $y \in M$ and a unique rational $r$ such that $x = y + r$.

Let $M_r := \lbrace{y + r: y \in M}\rbrace$ for each rational number $r$.

Then we have a partition of $\mathbb R$ into a countable number of disjoint sets:
$$(1.1) \qquad \mathbb R = \bigcup \lbrace{M_r: r \in \mathbb Q}\rbrace$$
where $\mathbb Q$ denotes the set of rationals.

Suppose $M$ is measurable.

First we note that $\mu(M) = 0$ is impossible as that would mean $\mu(\mathbb R) = 0$ using $(1.1)$.

But then $\mu(M) > 0$ means:
$$\mu([0, 1]) \ge \mu \left({\bigcup \lbrace{M_r: \text{$r \in \mathbb Q$ and $0 \le r \le 1$} }\rbrace }\right)$$

$$= \sum_{r \in \mathbb Q: 0 \le r \le 1} \mu(M_r) = \infty$$

because each $M_r$ would have to have the same measure as $M$. $\blacksquare$

That's the gist of it.

The question has been raised as to the validity of the line:

$$\mu([0, 1]) \ge \mu \left({\bigcup \lbrace{M_r: \text{$r \in \mathbb Q$ and $0 \le r \le 1$} }\rbrace }\right)$$

A respondent claims that the above is wrong and a mistake in Jech, and that it should be:

$$\mu([0, 2]) \ge \mu \left({\bigcup \lbrace{M_r: \text{$r \in \mathbb Q$ and $0 \le r \le 1$} }\rbrace }\right)$$

While that latter statement is indeed obvious, it has been pointed out that it is in no way clear that:
$$\mu([0, 1]) \ge \mu \left({\bigcup \lbrace{M_r: \text{$r \in \mathbb Q$ and $0 \le r \le 1$} }\rbrace }\right)$$
because while:

$$[0, 2] \supseteq \bigcup \lbrace{M_r: \text{$r \in \mathbb Q$ and $0 \le r \le 1$} }\rbrace$$

it is most definitely not the case that:

$$[0, 1] \supseteq \bigcup \lbrace{M_r: \text{$r \in \mathbb Q$ and $0 \le r \le 1$} }\rbrace$$

because elements of $M_r$ are of the form $y + r$ where $0 \le y \le 1$ and $0 \le r \le 1$.

So, did Jech make a mistake when he wrote:

$$\mu([0, 1]) \ge \mu \left({\bigcup \lbrace{M_r: \text{$r \in \mathbb Q$ and $0 \le r \le 1$} }\rbrace }\right)$$

... or is it just that he used something subtle in the above?

I can see where my respondent is coming from, but before I am able to declare that Jech is actually *wrong* I would welcome a second opinion and perhaps a proof as to exactly *why* he is wrong, by demonstrating that:

$$\mu([0, 1]) < \mu \left({\bigcup \lbrace{M_r: \text{$r \in \mathbb Q$ and $0 \le r \le 1$} }\rbrace }\right)$$

Comment: $M_r$ should be defined with the extra condition $0\leq y+r \leq1 $.

Comment: @geetha290krm well you could so define $M_r$, but the point is that the measure of $M_r$ does not matter exactly what the specific values in it are, because it's translation invariant. If I've got that right, which is uncertain because my understanding of the fundamentals of measure theory is shaky.

Comment: $[0, 1] \supseteq \bigcup \lbrace{M_r: \text{$r \in \mathbb Q$ and $0 \le r \le 1$} }\rbrace$ would be true with that definition.

Comment: @geetha290krm yes that's as maybe, but it does not answer the question as to whether the statement under investigation is wrong *without* so redefining $M_r$.

Comment: I think the extra condition proposed by @geetha290krm would invalidate the last bit of the proof, that each $M_r$ has the same measure as $M$. With Jech's definition, each $M_r$ is a translate of $M$, but that's no longer the case with the extra condition.